# Forked a repo. The master added commits. How do I fetch those additions?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-pull, git-fork, git-fetch

So, I recently started contributing to Open Source projects on Github. Until now, I was just putting my own personal projects up there.

Now, I forked a repo of an org that I found interesting. But, I see that that org has added commits to the master. I believe that my work can result in a merge conflict.

What I need help with:

- I need to know how to pull the code that has been committed in the master branch of the org to my forked master branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to sync your fork to the original master by doing the following:

1. Specify the original repository as a new remote upstream repo

   ```
   git remote add upstream https://github.com/ORIGINAL_OWNER/ORIGINAL_REPOSITORY.git
   ```

   You can then run **git remote -v** to confirm the upstream repository has been added correctly
2. Fetch from upstream branches (master commits will be in upstream/master)

   ```
   git fetch upstream
   ```
3. Merge the changes from the upstream master into your local master (bringing your fork in sync)

   ```
   git merge upstream/master
   ```

For a full step by step guide please see https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Whilst I appreciate just dumping links as an answer isn't appropriate in most occasions, for this the link is to a clear and concise step by step guide. I'm not entirely sure what benefit there is in me copy and pasting it into the answer directly. However if that is what would be preferred I can do it...

Comment: Problematic part is that if the link ever goes down your answer will be useless. And what's needed is mere 3 git commands.

Comment: Fair enough, I have changed the answer to only state the essential parts and left the link for reference.